# Is using constraintLayout mandatory in Android studio?

Tags: android

Sorry, I'm a beginner Android developer so I aplogize if my question sound odd to you senior guys but I'm really not understand this new feature.

If someone can explain in easy words how to use constraintLayout that would be great because at the moment I'm really struggling to understand it. It becomes very hard to position elements inside constaintLayout.

also can I use alternatives like RelativeLayout as a base layout?

Comment: No, it's not mandatory. You're free to use whichever ViewGroup you prefer.

Comment: "also can I use alternatives like RelativeLayout as a base layout?" -- yes. "If someone can explain in easy words how to use constraintLayout" -- that is well beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow answer. Beyond [the training guide](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html), there are many YouTube videos on it, plus books and courses that cover `ConstraintLayout`. If you have *specific* questions about using `ConstraintLayout`, feel free to ask a separate Stack Overflow question.

Comment: how can I do that?I mean when I try to delete constraintLayout by hitting delete nothing happens. @commonsWare will I have to do it manually by going into the xml file? if so how?please give an example

Comment: @soche123: When you create a new layout resource, the new-resource dialog will ask what root element you want to use. When editing an existing layout resource, you can change the root element in the "Text" sub-tab, where you can edit the XML for the layout resource.

Comment: @commonsWare when I create a new layout resource file, in the root element it is already filled with this "android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout". Also what specific changes I need to make in text editor of xml to the root element? thanks

Comment: "in the root element it is already filled with this "android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout"" -- correct. You would replace that with something else, such as `RelativeLayout`. "Also what specific changes I need to make in text editor of xml to the root element?" -- you would replace `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout` with whatever you want (e.g., `RelativeLayout`). If you have further questions, use the "Ask Question" button to ask separate questions.

Comment: yeah that worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is not mandatory, but it's the newest layout and it is more powerful than RelativeLayout or LinearLayout. You can even achieve the behavior of both these layouts by using ConstraintLayout.

Comment: Here are some links if you feel like wanna learn it: 
[ConstraintLayout codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/constraint-layout/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0)
[Build a Responsive UI with ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html)
[ConstraintLayout](https://constraintlayout.github.io/)

Comment: thanks I have bookmarked it. I will read in a moment. But is it really complex or it is just me not giving it time to understand?

Comment: @soche123 Yes, it looks complex at the beginning, but it's not that difficult! Give it a try! One thing that helped me a lot was "it was made to be used in design mode (the graphic editor)" and then I made the codelab I mentioned here and it was all clear. Good luck!